# ¿como cambiar texto en HTML con JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html

Hola a toda la comunidad, cuando deje de programar lo mas moderno era turbopascal, ahora quiero actualizarme, y lo siguiente funciona en la consola, pero no en la página ¡alguien sabe que estoy haciendo mal?

```js
 texto1 =['esto es 1', 'esto es 2', 'esto es 3', 'esto es cuatro' , 'esto es último'];
     for (let index = 0; index < texto1.length;index++ ){    document.getElementById(textoCambiante).innerHTML = texto1[index];
        setTimeout:2000 }
```

```html
<head>
    <title>Hola Mundo!</title>
</head>
<body> <h1 id='textoCambiante'>    esto debe cambiar </h1>    
     <script src="app.js" ></script> 
 </body>
```

Comment: Tienes que poner el id entre comillas: ` document.getElementById("textoCambiante")`

Comment: El texto que aparece dentro de las Etiquetas h1 debería cambiar cada dos segundos, por la cadena almacenada en el array,

Answer (score 2):

Si necesitas que el texto cambie cada 2 segundos tienes que utilizar setInterval. También tienes que poner el id entre comillas porque es una cadena de texto y no el nombre de una variable.

```js
 texto1 =['esto es 1', 'esto es 2', 'esto es 3', 'esto es cuatro' , 'esto es último'];
   
let n = 0;//un contador utilizado como index del array texto1
setInterval(function(){  document.getElementById("textoCambiante").innerHTML = texto1[n%texto1.length];
n++                       
}, 2000);
```

```html
<h1 id='textoCambiante'>esto debe cambiar </h1>
```

Answer (score 0):

Lo único que le esta haciendo falta son las comillas simples en el método getElementById():

```
<head>
<title>Hola Mundo!</title>
 </head>
 <body> <h1 id='textoCambiante'>    esto debe cambiar </h1>    <script src="app.js" ></script> </body> </html>


var texto1 =['esto es 1', 'esto es 2', 'esto es 3', 'esto es cuatro' , 'esto es último'];
var cuadroTexto=document.getElementById('textoCambiante');

 for (let index = 0; index < texto1.length;index++ ){
    cuadroTexto.innerText = texto1[index];
    setTimeout:2000 
}
```

Comment: Ok no sabía.....